# Creating a Notification-Handling App for a Custom Smartwatch on Windows Phone 8.x using C#

Tags: c#, notifications, windows-phone-8.1

I found [this](http://www.oswatch.org/) website which demonstrates a really cool custom smartwatch that uses Bluetooth LE to comunicate with a smartphone. The only problem is that the only smartphones it supports are iOS devices. So I decided to make a Windows Phone app for it. My trouble now is that I can't find any way to receive notifications from other apps such as Messages, Facebook, and Email. Does anyone know how to do this? I searched [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/) but I could only find ways to receive your own notifications.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know this is the only way.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.background.pushnotificationtrigger.aspx